# How to get job status of crawl tasks in nutch

Tags: nutch

In a crawl cycle, we have many tasks/phases like *inject,generate,fetch,parse,updatedb,invertlinks,dedup* and an *index* job.
Now I would like to know is there any methodologies to get ***status*** of a crawl task(whether it is running or failed) by any means other than referring to hadoop.log file ? 
To be more precise I would like to know whether I can track status of a generate/fetch/parse phase ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always run Nutch with Hadoop in pseudo or fully distributed mode, this way you'll be able to use the Hadoop UI to track the progress of your crawls, see the logs for each step, access the counters (extremely useful!).

Comment: Can I start a nutch server in fully distributed mode(on top of hadoop) and use nutch REST api for the same ?

Comment: Don't know, I never used the REST API. If not then that's a serious limitation, Nutch can run in local mode but it really shines when distributed

Comment: I searched over the web and found nothing helpful. I would like to expose nutch as a service in distributed mode.

Comment: @Sachin Nutch has a user mailiing list, would be the right place to ask